# How to create an association with from two columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two tables, `users` and `couples`. The `couples` table has a pair of foreign keys `lead_id` and `follow_id` which point to the `users` table. I would like for the `User` class to have a `has_many` association to `Couple` which selects all couples in which a given user was a lead or a follow. I can do this using `finder_sql` and SQL like so:

```
has_many :couples, class_name: 'Couple', finder_sql:
    proc { <<-SQL
      SELECT couples.* FROM users
        JOIN couples ON (couples.lead_id = users.id
                          OR couples.follow_id = users.id)
      WHERE users.id = #{self.id}
    SQL
  }
```

This works fine, but `:finder_sql` is apparently deprecated, so I'm looking for another way. The best I have gotten is using a custom association scope like this:

```
has_many :couples, -> {
  joins('JOIN couples ON (couples.lead_id = users.id OR couples.follow_id = users.id)')
    .select('couples.*')
}, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'id'
```

But this causes ActiveRecord to return `User` objects rather than `Couple` objects. Is there a (non-deprecated) way to do this?

Sorry if the title is unclear, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: May be you can try to use the Couple class_name and join it to `users` table instead of using User class_name joined to `couples`

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the docs (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) you may be able to get away with just this:

Users model:

```
has_many: :couples, as: lead
Has_many: :couples, as: follow
```

Couples model:

```
belongs_to :users
```

Also, look at the self joins section if you are attempting to relate leaders and followers.

Hope this helps.